# Build logs of two projects in a common file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, msbuild-4.0

I have 2 projects in my solution i want the build log of both of them to be common file.

But on specifying it as a common file the build log of the first project doesn't get appended by the build log of the second file instead it only contains build log of second project.

Is there any way to make it get append other then running a batch file in the post built event to copy contents of two log files in single file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `/fileLoggerParameters` (Short form: `/flp`) with the `Append` parameter. E.g.:

```
msbuild your.sln /flp:LogFile=MyLog.log;Append
```

Comment: msbuild need to be done from command line right.Is there any option without using command line.Thanks for the response....

Comment: I guess not. Outside Visual Studio you need a build server like TFS or similar to pass arguments. But for client side running from command line is the most simple option.